# How to make an array out of objects automatically

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi guys right now I'm making my array like this:

```
var piece1 = new DialoguePiece(null, questions[0], 0, 0, 4, 1);
var piece2 = new DialoguePiece(null, questions[1], 1, 0, 2, 3);
var piece3 = new DialoguePiece(scripts[1], null, 2, 1, 2, 2);
var piece4 = new DialoguePiece(scripts[2], null, 3, 1, 3, 3);
var piece5 = new DialoguePiece(scripts[0], null, 4, 0, 5, null);
var piece6 = new DialoguePiece(scripts[3], questions[2], 5, 4, 6, null);
var piece7 = new DialoguePiece(scripts[4], null, 6, 5, 7, null);
var piece8 = new DialoguePiece(scripts[5], null, 7, 6, null, null);

var pieces = [piece1, 
              piece2,
              piece3,
              piece4,
              piece5,
              piece6,
              piece7,
              piece8];
```

But I am wondering is there an easier way to do this? Like for example:

```
var pieces = GetObjectsByName(DialoguePiece);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Who decides what the arguments to `DialoguePiece` are?

Comment: Me at the moment

Comment: Instead if writing `var piece1 = ` just push the elements to array directly like `pieces.push(new DialoguePiece())`

Comment: Maybe replace `var piece1 =  ...` with `pieces.push(...)`?

Comment: Then I see no way to automate this. There's no apparent pattern in the way you pass arguments to the constructors.

Comment: @ionut g. Stan he does not want to automate construction, but rather keep track of instances

Comment: @Jonasw yeah, I figured it might be that after reading your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function DialoguePiece(){
  DialoguePiece.all.push(this);
  ...
} 
DialoguePiece.all=[];
```

You could simply store them in an array, everytime the constructor is called ( being a property of the constructor itself makes it easy to reference ). To access you can do:

```
for(var i=0;i++<10;)
  new DialoguePiece();

console.log(DialoguePiece.all);
//its a normal array, so you could also do:
console.log(DialoguePiece.all.map(dia=>dia.name||"doesnt exist"));
```

Comment: While this _does_ solve the problem, it's very unnatural looking to me. It encourages global state (technically "static" from an OO POV), which might give OP some bad habits later on.

Comment: @byxor better way?

Comment: There isn't a better way to do what the OP asked. They'd be better off just writing an array literal IMO.

Comment: @byxor im not quite shure if an arrayliteral would be better... Actually im not quite shure what you mean with *global state*

Comment: The `all` property is tied to the constructor function itself, rather than instances of DialoguePieces. In a language like Java, this would be `static`, which is considered global. -- It's not global in a javascript sense.

Comment: Besides. We're beating a dead horse now. Your solution works, but the OP shouldn't want to do this at all.

Comment: I'd rather put this logic into a factory function than the constructor itself. So I can have at least multiple factories that don't interfere with each other. Where each one can have its own distinct state.

Comment: Depending on how visible the `DialoguePieces` constructor is, any two or more pieces of code that access `DialoguePieces.all` will be statically tied together (except JS is a bit more forgiving with this). It's a bit like how some people consider the singleton pattern an anti-pattern. It's debatable.

Comment: @Jonasw, it would be *pretty much* / *almost* the same code, but with an imprtant difference: usability, scalability and less prone to errors, because each factory can be distinct from all the other ones.